# Strange behavior with Django register view

Tags: django

I have server and app. In app I send JSON to register view.

JSON looks like:

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type : "POST",
        url : BASE_URL+"register/",
        data: {username: un, password1: ps1, password2: ps2, email: e},
    });
```

And my view:

```
def register(request):
    form = RegistrationFormUniqueEmail(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = RegistrationView().register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
```

rest of code it's doesn't matter because in this above line getting me an error.

```
new_user = RegistrationView().register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
TypeError: register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password2'
```

It's works recently on python 2.7, but now I migrate to python 3.5

Could you help me?

**UPDATE**

When I checked this:

```
 form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
 if form.is_valid():
    print (form.cleaned_data)
    ...
```

I got nice dict

```
{'password2': 'pass', 'email': 'asd@asd.asd', 'username': 'user', 'password1': 'pass'}
```

Comment: This is a bizarre thing to do. Why are you calling another view's method? The registration logic should be in the form or the model.

Comment: I have few more operations after register and I need to call this method manually.

Answer (score 0):

The data might not be attached to the request.POST 
I would investigate RegistrationFormUniqueEmail(request.body) which should be json encoded. Otherwise cast it to json for python3.

import json

data = json.jsonload(request.body)

RegistrationFormUniqueEmail(data)

Comment: When I'm trying data= json.load(request.body) I got: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'